# Version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by libpng16.so.16) in Debian

Tags: debian

I know this is basically the exact question as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306849/, but the answer there does not seems right to me, as they all saying creating a `libz.so.1` symlink. However,

In my Debian bullseye, I already have `libz.so` and `libz.so.1`, both symlinking to `libz.so.1.2.11`.

So this seems to be a problem that `libpng16.so.16` insists on a lower version of ZLIB (v1.2.9), while mine is already `v.1.2.11`, right?

Here are all the details:

```
$ mitmweb
/usr/bin/x-www-browser: /tmp/_MEIi9PAKI/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found
 (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)

cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

$ ls -l libz.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     36 2020-02-24 16:07 libz.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 2020-02-24 16:07 libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.11
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 113088 2020-02-24 16:07 libz.so.1.2.11

$ apt-cache policy libpng16-16:amd64
libpng16-16:
  Installed: 1.6.37-3
  Candidate: 1.6.37-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.6.37-3 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff01872000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa21425d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa214119000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa213f54000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa2142c2000)

$ realpath /usr/bin/x-www-browser
/export/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t an issue with the `zlib1g` or `libpng16-16` packages in Debian, it’s a bug in [the binaries provided by `mitmweb`](https://mitmproxy.org/). They include a number of libraries which are unpacked in a temporary directory at runtime; `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set to the temporary directory so that the dynamic linker will use the libraries there. This works fine for the binaries shipped by `mitmweb`, but `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is passed down to the browser which `mitmweb` attempts to start.

The bundle of libraries includes `libz` version 1.2.8, which is too old to satisfy the requirements of `libpng16-16`. As a result, the browser, which needs `libpng16-16`, fails to start. (The binaries are built on an old distribution [so that they won’t end up requiring new libraries](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/2445).)

There’s no simple fix for `mitmweb` itself, short of rebuilding it from source, but you can easily work around the error: wait for `mitmweb` to start, and open http://localhost:8080 in your browser (or whatever URL is appropriate, if you specified another host or port using `--web-host` or `--web-port`).

(Interested readers can see the structure of `mitmweb` without running it by analysing it with `binwalk`.)